# Detecting scroll-stop on window and div

Tags: jquery

I have divs with overflow:scroll and i want to fade-in a extra-div when the user stops scrolling on the page (plus timeout). 
This means I need to detect if the user is stop scrolling in one of the divs and on the whole page - $(window).

if the user scrolls again the fade-in should be stopped

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
  $('#extra').stop().fadeOut(30, "linear" );
});
```

i use this code at the moment from: http://jsfiddle.net/wtRrV/219/

```
$.fn.scrollStopped = function(callback) {    
  var $this = $(this), self = this;

  $this.scroll(function(){                  
    if ($this.data('scrollTimeout')) {
      clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
    }

    $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback,500,self));
  });
};
```

and

```
$('#div1, #div1').scrollStopped(function()
  $('#extra').delay(3000).fadeIn(2000, "linear" );
});
```

my basic question at the moment is: how can i combine this two selector -`$('#div1, #div1')` - with `$(window)` to start the fade-in when the user stop scrolling in one of the divs and/or on the whole page.

thanks for any help!

Comment: Bit of a misleading title. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var combined = $(window).add('#div1');

combined.scrollStopped(function()
  $('#extra').delay(3000).fadeIn(2000, "linear" );
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtRrV/235/)